# Window Azure vs Citrix Xenapp

Tags: azure, citrix

Current my company delivers our software to our customers through a Citrix Xenapp Server.  As administrators we are able to launch instances of the servers and our customers are only able to launch their specific application

My Question is does Windows Azure also offer this type of environment.  I am looking to deploy a new version of our application and I am leaning towards Azure, but if that is the direction we go in I would like to migrate all of our existing system to Azure and not maintain both Azure and Citrix.

Answer (score 0):

Greg,

In principle yes you can do this, but you can't just plug in Azure as a direct replacement for XenApp (with zero/minimal effort). Azure effectively has it's own runtime. While it is Windows based and there is certainly potential to reuse code in an existing app in an Azure equivalent, you would need to re-write your app to make it run in Azure.

Given your app is running on XenApp it is likely it is a fat client app, i.e. most of its logic lives in the main executable that you run on XenApp, with potentially some other back end services being utilised. In comparison you should think of Azure as a platform for providing web apps. So you would re-architect the app as an Azure hosted web app, then you could deploy it via Azure in a multi-tenanted manner to your customers who would then access it through a browser rather than a Citrix Receiver.

Regards,
Donovan

Comment: Donovan, thank you for the info you are exactly correct with your description of our system, with the addition that every one of our 100+ clients has a customized version of our application.  I would like to move all of our new client and old one willing to upgrade into a  multi-tenant web app.  The problem is alot of our clients are funded by grant money and will most likely not upgrade for years.  In this scenario I do not really want to have to maintain 2 sets of servers. Is there a way to move theses systems into the Azure environment with our completely having to redo the front end.

Comment: Well Azure does have a VM role that allows you to run your own Windows VMs in Azure. So you could possibly setup a XenApp environment that runs in Azure. I haven't really seen anything about using XenApp on Azure like this, so I don't know whether it will actually work or is supported by Citrix. All the articles/blogs about running XenApp in the cloud generally talk about using Amazon as the cloud provider.